# Классификация итераторов

Tags: c++

Как в коде применяются классы классификации итераторов:

```
input_iterator_tag
output_iterator_tag
forward_iterator_tag
bidirectional_iterator_tag
random_access_iterator_tag
```

понятно что класс передается как параметр шаблона, а что дальше делает с ним шаблонный класс.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Категории задаются типом, далее этот тип используется для выбора правильной перегрузки функции, обрабатывающей контейнер с помощью того или иного типа итератор.

Пример можно посмотреть, например, на [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags)